# Does C++11 use move semantics to do copy-to-assign optimization?

Tags: c++, c++11

Assume I have a class called Foo that has suitable move constructors/assignment operators defined.  Given the following pseudocode:

```
Foo some_func(Foo var) { 
    <update var>
    return var;
}

int main() { 
    Foo var;
    var = some_func(var);
}
```

Will C++11 automatically use move semantics when passing var to some_func, and again to re-assign to var, since the original value of var would be destroyed anyways?  I *think* this would be a safe optimization and it would let you write pure functions that are as fast as passing references/pointers.  If it can't do it, why not?  I know it can be forced with std::move but it'd be cool if it was automatic.

Comment: This optimization - moving the local variable `var` to the function parameter - is illegal if it has observable side effects. For example, if move-construction of the parameter of `some_func` or `some_func` itself throws, the local variable in `main` could be left modified / in an invalid state.

Comment: That's a good answer, though it seems overly cautious of them.  I have a hard time coming up with a non-contrived move constructor that might throw.

Comment: @gct Even a move constructor may sometimes require memory allocations, and memory allocations can always throw.

Comment: The assignment is a move assignment. The construction is a copy construction.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Will C++11 automatically use move semantics when passing var to some_func,

No, that is a copy construction, because `var` is an lvalue.

The language does not allow the compiler to do anything else. The only time an lvalue is implicitly moved instead of copied is when returning it from a function, e.g. this line in `some_func` will use the move constructor:

```
return var;
```

> and again to re-assign to var, since the original value of var would be destroyed anyways?

That will use Foo's move assignment operator, because it's assigning an rvalue to `var`.

You would avoid any copies if you used `some_func(std::move(var))` or if you wrote it like this instead:

```
Foo var = some_func({});
```

This creates a temporary which initializes the function argument, then returns the function parameter, which will use a move, then `var` will be move-constructed, but the move can be elided. So the compiler is allowed to perform only a default construction for the function parameter and a move construction for `var`.

Comment: I'm fairly sure you can't elide copying/moving from a function parameter.

Comment: @T.C. oops, you're right - the parameter can be treated as an rvalue rather than lvalue for selecting the constructor, but it can't then be elided. I'll correct that.